# Show Discount Block in Cart Totals using Ajax

Tags: cart, controllers, ajax, totals

I am working on a custom module where I need to show my discount in cart totals. I am following [Classyllama](http://www.classyllama.com/blog/unravelling-magentos-collecttotals-example) and [Turnkey](http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-development-add-total-row-checkout/) blog posts in order to achieve the same.

I have come to a point where my custom discount is shown in cart totals block. But that is not ajax based. User have to click on a submit button and then only I can see by block being added in cart totals.

What I need to do now is when I click on a checkbox, it should call my controller and after some processing show my block added in cart totals without page reload, as shown below.

[image]

```
<script>
function updateCreditPoints()
{
    var amount = $('discount_amount').value;


    new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $myFormAction?>", {
           method: 'post',
           postBody: "discount="+$('discount_amount').value,
           onComplete: function(data) {
                //somecontainer to update
            }
    });
}
</script>
```

If checkbox is selected, then container should show the discount block else it should not.

I am unable to find what code should be written in `controller action` to show my discount block on ajax request.

Please Help.

Thanks.

Comment: post the code of the controller or specifically of this form action.